# Breaking a stick of $n$ units into $n$ sticks

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you break a stick of length $n> 1$ into $n$ pieces of unit length? At each step you can break the stick into two sticks of integer lengths.

I just want an insight into the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You'll break the stick $n-1$ times, once each at each integer position $i$ with $1 \le i \le n-1$, and this can be done in any order.  So how many ways are there to arrange $n-1$ things in an order?

Comment: It will be $(n-1)!$..

Comment: But for $n=3$ there's just one way to do it.

Comment: @AdityaParson: You can break it at position 1, then position 2, or you can break it at position 2, then position 1. That's two ways.

Comment: Okay. I get that.

Comment: Let $s_{n}$ denotes this number. Is the following recursion-formula
a correct interpretation of your question: $s_{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}s_{k}s_{2n-k}$
and $s_{2n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}s_{k}s_{2n+1-k}$? Then indeed $s_{3}=1$.

Comment: @AdityaParson I wouldn't be surprised if this answer does not really meet your question. I think you are right in saying that there is only one way for $n=3$. If I 'break a stick' then I do that without putting some orientation on it. Only the length of the two parts play a role.

Comment: @drhab Exactly.

Comment: Also the source of the problem isn't very explicit about that part either.

Comment: Do you understand my recursion-formula?